# Canny edge for keypoint detectors in SURF

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, edge-detection, surf, feature-extraction

I want to use Canny edge as a keypoint detector in SURF but I am not sure if it is possible to do so. Maybe I might sound silly but I just thought to confirm before I spend time doing it as I am new to image processing. Please advice me if I can use canny edge with surf.

Comment: I think it is better to apply directly on image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you help me further on this. You meant i determine the edges on the image and apply surf to the edge image instead.

Comment: no, he meant, that applying canny will result in a binary image, and that might degrade the SURF detection. so stick with your original image.

Comment: +1 thank you berak for making it clear.